# can not resolve R

Tags: android, android-studio

Initially Android Studio shows 'can not resolve ...' but after I clean and rebuild the project it can not resolve `R`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you see the left bottom corner, it says `...the build finished with 7 errors`. Can you post the log?

Answer (score 1):

`Gradle build finished with 7 error(s) in 12s 393ms (2 minutes ago)`

This means that your app failed to build. The way Android Studio works is that the `R` class is generated as part of the build - it was deleted when you cleaned the project, and since the build failed it could not be recreated.

This is a red herring error - it's an actual build error, but it's caused by another. If you open the Messages tab, you'll see a few errors - the `Unresolved reference: R` ones will be there, but so will be others. If you manage to fix them, them the `R` ones will fix themselves. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you read the error throughly, you will found the following:

```
error:resource drawable/ic_launcher(aka com.example.paramjeet.service:/drawable/ic_launcher) not found
```

That means you don't have any image named `ic_launcher` in `res/drawable/` or `res/drawable***/`

You only have ic_launcher in `/res/mipmap/`. So, change to it.

Comment: after set  ic_launcher it show error that Error:(10, 14) error: duplicate class: com.example.paramjeet.service.R                 photo of error log is edit above

Comment: clean up your project.